# NSDate without timezone for a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker which I'm using to choose the opening time of a shop.

The problem is that the date picker is changing the displayed time depending on the timezone, but I just want to show the time exactly as it appears in the NSDate.

For example, my NSDate is set as 2001-01-01T09:15:00Z.  i.e. 9:15am on 1st Jan 2001.

I set my UIDatePicker date to this date, but when I open the app in Spain (which is GMT-1) I see 10:15am.

I'm not using a dateFormatter here - just regular NSDate.  Is there a way of telling the UIDatePicker to ignore the timezone?

Or perhaps I shouldn't be storing the time as an NSDate because of the inherent timezone issues?

Comment: Set the date picker timezone to UTC.  The value in an NSDate is (conceptually, at least) stored as UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDatePicker has timeZone property - The time zone reflected in the date displayed by the date picker.
See if that will help you...

Comment: Although I should note that I'm getting a UIDatePicker bug which is showing the WRONG hour, but anyway.  I'll deal with that separately.